# RemoveEditor in a shared drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to remove editors in a shared drive, in my drive the code works ok, but when I run it in the "shared drive" put this message,

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtinZ.png),  [other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFiGc.png) and
[the file in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb8jM.png)

anyone can tell me a different  method, that i can use?

```
function cambiarPermisosEdicion (a) {
  var fol = DriveApp.getFolderById(a);
  var files = fol.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    var peopleToEdit = file.getEditors();
    for (var i=0 ; i < peopleToEdit.length; i++){
      
          file.removeEditor(peopleToEdit[i]);
          file.addViewer(peopleToEdit[i]);
    }
  }
  }
```

Hi, I'm already a content manager of the shared drive, for that i dont understand why shows that  error message.

[Content manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRjv6.png)

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> Exception: Cannot use this operation on a shared drive item

in most cases means that you are a `Contributor`, `Commenter` or `Viewer` of the shared Drive.

### In order to change file permissions you need to be a `Content manager` or `Manager`.

See [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554?hl=en) for more information.

[image]

UPDATE

If you are the content manager of the shared Drive, you should not run into permission issues. However, as a workaround you also have the option to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) instead of the `DriveApp`.

For this:

- Make sure to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) the `Advanced Drive Service`
- Use methods of the [Permissions resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions)
- Write your request as following:

```
function cambiarPermisosEdicion (a) {
 var fol = DriveApp.getFolderById(a);
 var files = fol.getFiles();
 
 while (files.hasNext()){
   var file = files.next();
   var fileId = file.getId();
   var permissions = Drive.Permissions.list(fileId).items[0];
   permissions.forEach(function(permission){ 
     Drive.Permissions.remove(fileId, permission.id);
   })
   var peopleToEdit = file.getEditors();
   for (var i=0 ; i < peopleToEdit.length; i++){
     var resource = {
       "role": "reader",
       "type": "user",
       "value": peopleToEdit[i]
     }
     Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, fileId);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm already a content manager of the folder, for that I dont understand why shows that  error message.

Comment: You need to a content manager of the SHARED DRIVE.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for your help ;).  My english is not very well, but what I wanted to say is that I'm a content manager of the "shared drive", and the Manager of the shared drive runs the code and show the same error.

Comment: Have a look at the alternative solution in my edited answer.